# Search and extract text out of a txt file

Tags: command-line, grep

I am looking for a tool that extracts lines of text out of a huge txt file based on keywords. The txt file is actually a system log file where each event falls on a new line.

I would for example type in "methodName1, methodName2, var3" and the program would return all the lines that contained either keyword.

Comment: grep/egrep. They are UNIX tools, but are available on Linux and Windows too.

Comment: Sweetness! I didn't know grep returned line by line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest syntax for multiple keywords like you show above would be grep or egrep:

```
grep -e methodName1 -e methodName2 -e var3 text.txt
egrep 'methodName1|methodName2|var3' text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed, Grep, AWK.

Pick your poison.

Usage:

```
sed  '!/keyword/d' input.txt
grep 'keyword' input.txt
awk '/keyword/ {print}'  input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Windows tool with a GUI try [Agent Ransack](http://mythicsoft.com/agentransack):

[image: searching log]